# Outlook message formatting issues with signutare

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

I have this weird issue in Outlook 2010 (we are also using Exchange 2010) where a person's signature is getting inserted in the middle of the message.  Some thing like this:

=========================================

{Line 1 text}

{Line 2 Number 1 text}

[signature]

{Line 3 Number 2 text}

{Line 4 Number 3 text}

.

.

.

{Line x text}

=========================================

The signature is handed down by Exchange and not created locally by a user.

Please help!!!

Comment: what is inserting the signature? this is not a feature that is built in to Exchange, so it must be a third party product.

Comment: Actually it comes from AD, the user's info (address, phone #, etc.) that gets filled out.

Comment: ok, the data comes from AD. but what feature or product actually does the replacement? again, there is no native feature in Exchange that does this.

Comment: The signature has to be either generated by Exchange or AD, we don't have 3rd party product for it installed.

Comment: @longneck - Exchange 2010 can do this, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an exchange expert, but it sounds you might have a transport rule in effect.  Can you please confirm?  Additional information is available [here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/migration-deployment/using-disclaimer-exchange-server-2010.html), [here](http://4sysops.com/archives/automatically-add-email-signaturesdisclaimers-with-exchange-2010/), and [here](http://blog.chrislehr.com/2009/07/exchange-2010-hub-transport-building.htm).

Comment: I am no expert either, obviously, but yes, that's what we do.

Comment: @George Cool.  So if that's the case, you'll need to edit/remove your respective transport rule to get rid of the automatic signature if you don't want it.

Comment: I do want it.  It just gets inserted in the middle of the message instead of the end as it suppose to.  That's the weird part!